# Extract two strings separated by specific character

Tags: powershell

I'm new on Powershell and I have to solve a problem. I've been looking for different solutions but I don't how I have to proceed... From a text file, I have to :

1. Extract two strings separated by a `"|"`.
2. Verify if both strings are the same or not.
3. If yes, so, I export results in txt file keeping only string1.
4. If not, i export results in txt file as string2.string1

For example, my file is like that :

```
column name
toulon|1|0|||||||wan|toulon
lille-test|1|0|||||||wan|Lille
```

Expected output is a txt file with :

```
toulon
lille.lille-test
```

I can provide source file and expected output if needed.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific errors are you getting? We won't just write things for you, we help people with specific issues. Also, your question doesn't make much sense since you have more than one string in each example...

Comment: please show all three lines - it LOOKS like you have a CSV file with the delimiter set to `|`. ///// also, you show `lille.lille-test` as the output from the  2nd line ... and that is NOT in the 2nd line. [*grin*] so ... please post the source & expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use the `-Split` operator to delimit based on the `|` character, perform the string comparison, and then join the result with `-Join` operator.

```
$Lines = Get-Content -Path "test.txt"
$lines | Foreach-Object {
    $splits = $_  -Split "\|"
    if ($splits[0] -eq $splits[-1]) {
        $splits[0]
    }
    else {
        $splits[-1,0] -Join "."
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome ! it was what i expected. Just have to send this output to a txt file. Thanks a lot